Findings from sp_blitzindex, need advices
I'm trying to perform some housekeeping activities on a very large SQL 2016 database, it's total size was about 10TB. This database has been running for many years without any actual housekeeping done. Apps guys have several jobs which will move datas from tables in this database to another database for archiving purposes. Fun Fact, both database sits on the SAME box!
Ok, so initially I ran blitzfirst(v8.21) and I notice there's findings of Forwarded Fetches/Sec high with 46,000 forward fetches recorded. Then I proceeded to execute blitzindex & the top priority from this shows Index Hoarder: Unused NC index with High Writes, which all referring to NC indexes belonging to a single table. As I am not part of the team which design and create this database from the beginning, I'm unable to confirm if this indexes are indeed not required. For this indexes will there be any issue if I just proceed to disable it?
Also for heaps, based on blitzindex's result, there's quite a number of heap tables & heap with NC index table found. Will it be helpful if I suggest the DB owner to consider creating clustered index to it?

You have a couple of different questions in here:
Is it okay to just disable indexes after observing them just once? No. It's possible that different workloads run on the box at different times, like at month-end or business closing. It's also possible that the indexes are used on different replicas, like Availability Groups replicas or log shipping replicas.
Should I suggest that someone else put in clustered indexes on their tables? I get nervous here when you say it's a 10TB database because putting a clustered index on a large table is a big operation. The entire table gets copied, and the entire operation is logged. You can blow up your log file sizes, which affects other replicas too.
I'd take a step back and ask, What's the problem you're trying to solve? It sounds like you're approaching a system that works, running a script you don't understand, and making changes to a production system that you don't understand. That strikes me as a pretty risky idea.
I'm not gatekeeping, and I'm not suggesting that you step away from the database. I'm just saying that change equals risk, and before you take any risks, you want to know that there's a reward. What makes this task the most important one on your to-do list right now? What are the users complaining about? What do their complaints sound like? You don't need to answer that here - Stack isn't really a platform for consulting - but when you answer those questions for yourself, it'll help guide whether you should really be poking around in these indexes on a system that might just be working fine.
